# Why doesn't the if statement execute?

Tags: python, if-statement

https://github.com/gabrirm/python-roulette-game.git

```
if betType == "red" and bet in red == True:
    self.balance += betprice[0] * 2
else:
    self.balance -= betprice[0]
    print("Oh, the ball landed on a black number :(. This is your current balance: ".format(self.balance))

if betType == "black" and bet in black == True:
    self.balance += betprice[0] * 2
else:
    self.balance -= betprice[0]
    print("Oh, the ball landed on a red number :(. This is your current balance: ".format(self. Balance))
```

So in this piece of code, when the user types `'red'`, why does the else statement keep executing, even though `betType == 'red' and bet in red == True`? both parts are true right? the else shouldn't execute.

Comment: What is `red` or `black`? This might be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: @KellyBundy I realized that was wrong, so edited my comment. Also, what I had before barely qualifies as an answer.

Comment: It might not have been nice as an answer, but you were clearly answering.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

If `A`, `B` and `C` are operands and `x` is a *comparison* operator, then:

`A x B x C` is equivalent to:

```
(A x B) and (B x C)
```

You have this situation in this part: `bet in red == True`

So now this line:

```py
betType == "red" and bet in red == True
```

is actually:

```py
(betType == "red") and (bet in red) and (red == True)
```

From [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), both `==` and `in` are comparison operators.

If you want your condition to work as expected put parenthesis around the membership testing like: `(bet in red) == True` or better is to leave it like `bet in red`. That's it. No need to compare to `True`:

```py
betType == "red" and bet in red
```

Comment: You are right, but I wrote that in an attempt to solve the issue, I previously had: and bet in red', but didn't work either... I guess it is a syntax problem when getting the value of betType from the user's input. That's my shot, but I certainly can't identify the problem. Thank you so much anyway :)